# Issue with nesting components with routing in a page in Next js 13 without changing the page

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, next.js13

How will I implement the product overview which have sub nav for the category in that page below in Next js 13. When click on the category on the sub nav, that specific category will show without changing the page but the link should change. I am able to do it without routing but I want men and women categories to have different link change but the part of the page should be unchange. [image]

Comment: put them on a dynamic route file like [category].js and get category with getStaticProps and getStaticPaths and pass it into props. THen u can filter with that category

Comment: btw the main page should move into this route with category like 'all' or something

Comment: What if I want to render the categories as individual components not fetched data. How will I do it?

Comment: I dont really understand your question. But u need data to render them, if u dont want to fetch data, u need local data

Comment: But don't you think it will take me to a new page? Remember I only want a section of the page to change. That is the contain of only the click category

Comment: if you want to only change the nav section i think use should your client side rendering. So you need to put 'use client' on top of the file and use react simple way that create state and make action to update state when click on category

Answer (score 0):

You can create common/shared components for both category list and category details page then create a file [id].js or [slug].js so when category is clicked should point to the details page([id].js) which will reuse those shared components and change only section which you want to show category details. ( I am assuming you understand Nextjs routing very well)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).